# Why do we might want to put class name before a method?

Tags: c++, templates, syntax

I have a code with the following structure:

```
aaa::bbb<ccc>
ccc::func_name(type1 arg1, type2 arg2)
{
   something1;
   aaa::bbb<ccc> obj_name(variable);
   something2;
}
```

It looks similar to function templates but in function templates we should put `template <class class_name>` before the method.

Comment: `bbb` is defined within a class or namespace called `aaa`. look up the scope resolution operator `::` in your nearest c++ textbook.

Comment: It looks like definition of class member `func_name` of class `ccc`, returning template class `bbb<T>` with substitution `ccc` defined in class or namespace `aaa`. Are you missing colon `ccc:(here)func_name`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`aaa::bbb<ccc>` is the type of the return value of `ccc::func_name()`.

Answer (score 4):

You mean something like this:

```
std::vector<Point>
Point::func_name(type1 arg1, type2 arg2)
{
   something1;
   std::vector<Point> obj_name(variable);
   something2;
}
```

it is a normal declaration of a method which returns another object which happens to be a instance of a template class. Someone obviously thought it is more readable than

```
std::vector<Point> Point::func_name(type1 arg1, type2 arg2) {...}
```

which means exactly the same